# Form action unfamiliar

Tags: actions, home-url, bloginfo

I am refactoring some code in the header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>

<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> <!-- leave this for stats -->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<div id="wrap">
         <div id="header">
         <a href="http://threegreenbirds.org" class="hlink"><h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1><div id="tagline"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
&nbsp;</a>
         <!--Main Navigation-->
         <div id="mainNav">
         <ul>
         <li><a href="http://threegreenbirds.org">Home</a></li>
         <?php /* EDIT THE MENU BY CHANGING ONLY THE NUMBERS AFTER INCLUDE*/ wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&include=8,14,10,12,16,6&title_li='); ?>
         </ul>

          <div id="search">
         <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" class="searchbox" size="20" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="searchbutton" />
</form>
                  </div>

         </div>
         <!--end main navigation-->



         </div>
```

One of the requirements is for me to change this to a mobile responsive website which I started to in the file above with this piece of code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I also added the body_class function and so where I have a question is when I looked at the form action, I see this:

```
action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/"
```

I have never seen anything like that before, but keep in mind I don't have 10+ years doing this. Typically speaking this is how I would develop the form action:

```
action="<?php esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"
```

So my question being, should I change it or is there a legitimate best practice being implemented here that I am not familiar with? I understand that the best practice is to go with esc_url() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generally, they will return the same URL**, as `bloginfo( 'url' )` will call `home_url` internally with any arguments, and the default first argument (`$path`) of `home_url` is the empty string. However, `bloginfo( 'url' )` will apply an additional filter to it, namely the `home_url` filter.

Common pratice is to use `home_url`, indeed with `esc_url` (even though `home_url()` returning an invalid URL will yield bigger problems anyway :-)). In WordPress core, `bloginfo( 'url' )` is practically never used anymore. Instead, `home_url( '/' )` is used.

So, summarizing: **use `esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )`**.